# How do I stop the attribute "position: fixed" at a certain point?

Tags: html

How do I stop the attribute "position: fixed" at a certain point so the button in my case, isn't kind of following the user when scrolling anymore. Because I have this footer at the bottom of my page and the "book now" button overlaps the footer and I don't want that. How do I "stop" the button just above the footer?

```js
const slideshowImages = document.querySelectorAll('#slideshow img');
let currentIndex = 0;

function showNextImage() {
  console.log(slideshowImages[currentIndex]);
  slideshowImages[currentIndex].style.display = 'none';
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % slideshowImages.length;
  slideshowImages[currentIndex].style.display = 'block';
}
console.log(slideshowImages);
setInterval(showNextImage, 5000);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.5em;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

p {
  margin: 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 1px;
  padding-left: 2.5%;
}

img {
  width: 90vw;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 12%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300 px;
}

#slideshow img {
  width: 170%;
  height: 170%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-button {
  font-family: Arial;
}

#menu ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

#menu a:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

.Infotext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 57%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.InfotextÜ {
  position: absolute;
  top: 53.5%;
  left: 40%;
  font-family: Arno Pro Caption;
  font-size: 2.0em;
}

.button-24 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 90%;
  left: 45.3%;
  background: #FF4742;
  border: 1px solid #FF4742;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 1px 2px 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: nunito, roboto, proxima-nova, "proxima nova", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 16px;
  min-height: 40px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px 43px;
  text-align: center;
  text-rendering: geometricprecision;
  text-transform: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button-24:hover,
.button-24:active {
  background-color: initial;
  background-position: 0 0;
  color: #FF4742;
}

.button-24:active {
  opacity: .5;
}

footer {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/Home.html" class="menu-button">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/Bildgalerie.html">Bildgalerie</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/Kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/in der Nähe.html">In der Nähe</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<header>
  <div id="slideshow">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dXTFKBo.jpg" alt="Slideshow image 1" style="display: block">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FzwZzYw.jpg" alt="Slideshow image 2" style="display: none">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kIS6CTy.jpg" alt="Slideshow image 3" style="display: none">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UUr5jSJ.jpg" alt="Slideshow image 3" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <p class="InfotextÜ">Paradiso Piccolo</p>
  <p class="Infotext">Das Paradiso Piccolo ist eine Ferienwohnung am See.</p>
  <img id="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/O0jKPtk.jpg" alt="Foto">
</header>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Das Apartment</h1>
  <p>Das Apartment ist für bis zu 6 Personen geignet.<br> Im Apartment gibt es außerdem:</p>
  <li>TV</li>
  <li>Stereo-Anlage</li>
  <li>WLAN (auf Wunsch)</li>
  <li>Bücher</li>
  <li>Brettspiele</li>
  <li>Decken- und tragbare Ventilatoren</li>
  <li>Infrarotheizung (gegen Aufpreis)</li>
  <li>Kühlschrank</li>
  <li>Mikrowelle</li>
  <li>Geschirr und Besteck</li>
  <li>Grundausstattung zum Kochen (Töpfe, Pfannen, Öl, Salz, Pfeffer)</li>
  <li>Gefrierschrank</li>
  <li>Herd (Gas und Elektro)</li>
  <li>Bügeleisen</li>
  <li>Geschirrspülmaschine</li>
  <li>Waschmaschine</li>
  <li>Wasserkocher</li>
  <li>Nespresso-Maschine</li>
  <li>Toaster</li>
  <li>Grill</li>
  <li>Holzkohle</li>
  <li>Grillbesteck</li>
  <li>Föhn</li>
  <li>Shampoo, Duschgel, Seife, etc</li>
  <li>Gartenmöbel (Liege, etc)</li>
  <li>Kostenlose Parkplätze</li>
  Bettwäsche und Handtücher sind selbst mitzunehmen!

  <h1>Standort</h1>
  <p>Via Cristoforo Colombo, 4, 37010 Brenzone VR, Italien</p>
  <iframe src="..."></iframe>
  <a href="https://www.airbnb.com/h/paradisopiccolo">
    <button class="button-24" role="button">Book Now!</button>
  </a>
</div>

<footer>
  <p>Paradiso Piccolo</p>
  <p>123 Main Street</p>
  <p>Anytown, USA</p>
  <button onclick="location.href='C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/Impressum.html'">Impressum</button>
  <button onclick="location.href='C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/Datenschutz.html'">Datenschutz</button>
</footer>
```

Comment: FYI, your second list markup is invalid. List items must be children of a list element.

Comment: Did you try using `position: sticky;`?

Comment: Please see [ask], then try to reduce the demo above to just what's needed for your question. There's a lot of distraction up there.